# Getting Facebook access token after login

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a small Django project that supports logging in via Facebook. I'm not using any pluings (like social-auth et al). I'm using FB's Javascript sdk to do the authentication.

I'm sending the access token back to my view, however, I need the FB user id. How do I query FB for the User ID from the access token?

I was sending the FB user id at first, however, any one can tamper with the it and I had no way to know if the ID is actually authentic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The user id should be available together with the access token, although, in order to verify it, you need to either extract it from a signed request, or retrieve it using an api call to https://graph.facebook.com/me using the token.

Comment: thanks for the reply but how to do I do the API call without authentication? On the server side, no one is authenticated yet.

Comment: You said you had the token, what else would you need?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. The token is on the client side (web page). I need to pass this token to the server and do a FB query using that token to get the FB user id. The user is getting authenticated using FB Javascript and I only send the token when the authentication was successful. All that is happening on the client side.

Comment: You are confusing me - as I said, you get the user_id and signed_request from the same data you get the access_token - so what are you missing? Also, if the user is authenticated (getLoginStatus), then you can easily call FB.api('/me', ...